# How can i get the android native Paste button onClick event....?

Tags: android

I need to copy the text, so i copied it by using ClipboardManager. Now when user log press on Any EditText then the Native Paste button opens, I need that paste buttons click listener. Because i need to make some changes before the copied text set to the EditText.

And how can i get the copied text in coding.

Comment: Can you manipulate the text before you put it into the clipboard instead of on paste?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. Unfortunately, you really don't have a way to know if the user decided to paste anything outside your app itself, so there is no On Click Listener for the Android paste button.

You can try to extend your app and make another paste button to possibly provide this functionality. However, you don't really need to, because what you seem to be asking for is to get the data the user copied to make changes, and you can retrieve this data from the clipboard by using getPrimaryClip() and coerceToText().

You can check the Android documentation for more details on these methods:
http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html